# Criteria for selecting variables(factors) in data mining

Tags: weka, data-mining

I have United Kingdom Road accident data with very large data set having 1 million records and approximately 66 factors like age, sex, speed limit, Light, Effect of Accident..etc. So, my professor wants me to select best 7 factors, but he did not say any criteria for selection for my final project.

I know we can not select any 7 factors, instead we need to do some analysis or mathematical calculations to select best 7 factors affecting the data. I am planning to do data mining in software Weka (j48 algorithm). Also i have XLminer plugin in excel. So, how do i need to come up with these **best 7 factors**?

once decision tree is formed with these 7 factors, i have to write a simple java program demonstrating output when these 7 values are entered in 7 different text boxes.

Comment: What is the target class? You only have accidents, no non-accidents, do you?

Comment: target class is Accident type. I have light crash, average crash, serious crash in accident type. I have only accident data in the data set

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at decision trees.

At every level, decision trees try to select the most important attribute; they offer a number of metrics to evaluate which attribute to choose... study these.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse for your reply. I used j48 decision tree and have following problems 1) confusion matrix has values zero in b,c columns as shown in fileone                                      2)The result is showing 88% accurate but when i try to generate decision tree i am getting filetwo                                 3) Can you tell me where there is option to select best variables among the variables present which is crucial for making decision or do i need to do some analysis with this statistical data?(this was the real question asked)

Comment: file1:http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/464465/fileone.png 
file2:http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/464466/filetwo.png